# need help using div and iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have created a little website (which will probably stay offline) to make some things easier. I created a hotbar with links so I can navigate to important sites more easily.

**The problem is:**

To iframe google into the webpage I had to use a proxy (I used hidemyass) because google blocks the use of iframes, but because the proxy site has a huge banner on top of every page you open trough it I moved the content inside of the iframe using margin top in CSS.

So the banner is still there but you can't see it but now whenever I open any other website in the same iframe without any banners it will hide part of the website and I don't want this.

So how do I make it hide the banner on top of the proxy page and still fully display any other page? I tried to give the div and iframe 2 names so that I could make 2 CSS statements but this doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
#frame1 {
    position:fixed !important;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    right:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    left:8%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
background-color: black
}

#frame2 {
width: 100%;
height: 131%;
    margin-top: -18.5%;
}


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="school/bronnen/css/main.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bronnen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
a href="http://2.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/czovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLw%3D%3D" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/google.jpg" alt="google" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://1.hidemyass.com/ip-5/encoded/czovL2dpdGh1Yi5jb20v" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/github.png" alt="github" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.awwwards.com" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/awwards.png" alt="awwards" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="https://7.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/czovL3d3dy5kcm9wYm94LmNvbS8%3D" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/dropbox.jpg" alt="dropbox" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/the-best-way-to-learn-css-2/" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/activetuts.png" alt="activetuts" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="https://7.hidemyass.com/ip-1/encoded/Oi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20v" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="stackoverflow" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<div name="frame1" id="frame1"><iframe src="school/bronnen/iframe/iframe.html" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>
<br>
<a href="http://player.highstrike.org/play/" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/dubstep.jpg" alt="dubstep" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.codecademy.com/learn" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/codecademy.png" width="7%" height="auto" alt=""></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.youtube.nl" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/youtube.png" alt="youtube" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://tpb.peterbishop.net/" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/piratebay.jpg" alt="piratebay" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="frame2"><img src="school/bronnen/pics/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="7%" height="auto"></a>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For obvious security reasons, you can not change contents of an `iframe` from its parent